# How to upgrade to specific release on Mac OS X (e.g. 10.7.3)?

Tags: macos

I have an old iPhone application which was created using Xcode 4.3.2. I want to get it running on Xcode. However, I am using OS X 10.9.5. So I get the error "This installation of Xcode 4.3.2 requires Mac OS X Lion". So I searched online and found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629445/this-installation-of-xcode-4-3-2-requires-mac-os-x-10-7-lion) about running Xcode 4.3.2 on VirtualBox. Now when I try to install Xcode 4.3.2 on Lion on VirtualBox, I get the error message "You have Mac OS X 10.7. The application requires Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later. How can I upgrade to 10.7.3 to get Xcode working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start from a base install - 10.n.0 then you can always directly update to a given 'point release' by using the Combo Updater for that release.

These appear to *always* remain available from Apple.

The Combo updater for 10.7.3 is at https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a so-called Combo Updater:

Download at least [OS X Lion Update 10.7.3 (Client Combo)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). This will update your 10.7.0 installation to 10.7.3 and contains all other point releases in between (10.7.1.& 10.7.2).

Other Lion Combo Updates are available here: [OS X Lion Combo Update search](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?q=OS%20X%20Lion%20Update%20%28Client%20Combo&src=globalnav_support&type=organic&page=search&locale=en_US)